# MacBook Pro doesn't detect power supply

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power-management

My MacBook Pro (early 2009) doesn't detect when the power supply is connected and doesn't charge. It behaves as if the power supply was not connected to the MBP. It has 56% battery left and runs fine otherwise.

I also noticed that the date was set back to before 2008.

I've tried to reset the SMC, but this didn't change anything. To reset the SMC, I've

- Turned off the computer
- Held Shift+Ctrl+Options(Alt)+ distinguished power (not a normal key on keyboard; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477516/in-iphone-simulator-how-to-type-the-sign-on-a-macbook-with-german-keyboard )
- Released all keys
- Turned on the computer by pressing power button again.

I've done this 2 times to no avail.

**Update 2015-07-22**
I noticed that I can make it charge by unplugging the power supply from both, the wall outlet and the MBP, and plugging it back in. Usually, I have to do this 2 or 3 times before it starts working and I need to have it unplugged for a minute or two. If I plug it back in after only 10 seconds, it doesn't work.
This sounds like a loose contact in the power supply or its cables, so I've also tried bending and shaking cables and parts while it didn't work, but that didn't have any effect. Thus, I presume it's not a loose contact.

Comment: that battery should be EOL ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD The battery seems to work fine. I can use the computer when battery powered in just the normal way. It used to last 2h or 3h just a few days ago.